# Search string for set of characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

So for some background: I've been going through learning python the hard way and have taken a little break to try doing a few fun things, I came across on a suggestion on daniweb, to try create a program in which you enter in a list of characters and it will then print out any word that contain all those characters.

I've figured out how to do it manually, here's the below code:

```
string = raw_input("Please enter the scrable letters you have: ")
for line in open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r').readlines():
    if string[0] in line and string[1] in line and string[2] in line:
        print line,
```

But I somehow cannot figure out how to get it to work by using loops (that way the user can enter in a list of characters of any length. I figured something like the below would work, but it doesn't appear to do so:

```
while i < len(string)-1:
   if string[i] in line: tally = tally + 1
   i = i + 1
if tally == len(string)-1: print line
else: i = 0
```

Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Change `if tally=len(string)-1` to `if tally=len(string)`

Comment: Still doesn't work, it for whatever reason prints any word that contains any one of the characters in the string.

Comment: can you give us an example of what is in '/usr/share/dict/words'?

Comment: It should also be `while i < len(string)`.  But really, you should be using a for construct instead of while: `for character in string:`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion happydave; I'll look into constructs, but the change does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) operations can come in handy here:

```
inp = set(raw_input("Please enter the scrable letters you have: "))
with open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r') as words:
    for word in words:
        if inp <= set(word):
            print word,
```

Comment: Ah yes, I came across sets but I was going through them in a convoluted manner as I can see now. This works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would use all with a comprehension for this ... and the comprehension is a loop

```
user_string = raw_input("Please enter the scrable letters you have: ")
for line in open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r').readlines():
    if all(c in line for c in user_string):
        print line,
```

Comment: This also gives me no output. I am on OSX 10.8.2 and using Python 2.7.2, should this still work?